# Java Generics: "Nested" type parameters?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, type-parameter

**EDIT:** Yes, this may be a duplicate. But whereas the other question is akin to "What is a chainsaw and how do I use it?" mine is more like "I am trying to drill a hole with this machine here and it doesn't work - what's up?". Of course the answer is "Don't use a chainsaw!" and easily found once you know you are dealing with a chainsaw.

But I didn't even know that my question was related to "raw types vs. wild cards" and therefore didn't find that question - so maybe this question is still useful for others like me.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:** Let's say I have the following data structure which represents an item in my user interface:

```
public static abstract class RowItem<T> {

    public final T value;

    public RowItem(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to do the following:

```
public static abstract class EpgRowItem<T> extends RowItem<Pair<String, T>> {

    public EpgRowItem(Pair<String, T> value) {
        super(value);
    }
}

public static final class EpgRowProgramItem extends EpgRowItem<Program> {

    public EpgRowProgramItem(Pair<String, Program> value) {
        super(value);
    }
}

public static final class EpgRowOtherDateItem extends EpgRowItem<LocalDate> {

    public EpgRowOtherDateItem(Pair<String, LocalDate> value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

So, in words: An `EpgRowItem` is a `RowItem` that contains a `Pair`, of which the first member is always a `String` and the second member can be anything. Furthermore, an `EpgRowProgramItem` is an `EpgRowItem` in which the second member of the pair is a `Program`. Likewise, an `EpgRowOtherDateItem` is an `EpgRowItem` in which the second member of the pair is a `LocalDate`.

This seems to work until I have this at some other place in my code:

```
List<OverlayPresenter.EpgRowItem> programs = ...;
OverlayPresenter.EpgRowItem epgRowItem = programs.get(0);
String channelId = epgRowItem.value.first; // DOESN'T COMPILE?!
```

I feel the compiler should know that `epgRowItem.value` must ALWAYS be a `Pair<String, ?>`, and consequently `epgRowItem.value.first` must ALWAYS be a `String`.

Actually, it doesn't even seem to know the first part, i. e. the following doesn't compile either:

```
Pair<String, ?> pair = epgRowItem.value; // epgRowItem.value is an Object?!
```

**What am I doing wrong?** Am I just asking too much of Java's generics?

Comment: Yes, now that I know the answer, it is of course a duplicate. But since I asked "the other way round" - starting with a concrete problem, not with a high level keyword - I think it's still a valid question and may be of use for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get into trouble because you are using the raw type `EpgRowItem` (a raw type is a parameterized type for which you do not specify type parameters; these exist because of backward compatibility with Java 1.4 and older):

```
List<OverlayPresenter.EpgRowItem> programs = ...;
OverlayPresenter.EpgRowItem epgRowItem = programs.get(0);
```

See: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Use a type parameter, or at least a wildcard:

```
List<OverlayPresenter.EpgRowItem<?>> programs = ...;
OverlayPresenter.EpgRowItem<?> epgRowItem = programs.get(0);
String channelId = epgRowItem.value.first;  // OK
```

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Until now I've always felt quite secure in using Java Generics, but that was new to me. Thank you very much!